# Excel VBA Remove last comma in formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, office365

I have a formula in EXCEL that concatenates a whole column of data into one big comma separated string.

I have data that looks like the below but I need the LAST comma to disappear or else I get a syntax error. What do I do?

My concatenate function is the following:

```
="'"&CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(L6:L43)&"',")
```

So what it's doing is EX:

I have a parts list in a column: SB-12-073, SB-18-88, SB-11-001 and I want them concatenated to say 'SB-12-073', 'SB-18-88', 'SB-11-001' but the SB-11-001 needs to have NO COMMA. Currently the concatenate function is pulling the comma over. The data is stored between L6 and L43

Comment: Why have you tagged this as `VBA`? Do you have code you need help debugging with? Also, what version of Excel have you got?

Comment: @JvdV Apologies - I'm using VBA for everything ELSE that I'm doing in this scenario, but I'm trying to just use basic EXCEL formulas for this one to avoid looping through the data (since I don't really know how) so that's a bit of a misnomer on my part. The version of Excel I have is Microsoft 365 MSO Version 2205 Build 16.0

Comment: Then avoid `CONCATENATE()` and use `TEXTJOIN()` isntead. Something like `="'"&TEXTJOIN("','",,L6:L43)&"'"` assuming at least a single item in the range.

Comment: @JvdV so on the topic of VBA, I labelled this concatenated string StkCdMstr to enter into my VBA. As part of my SQL I have a line that is to enter this whole string into one big list.
So I'm trying to basically show something like this::

    " where A.StockCode in ("& StkCdMstr &") " & _

will now become 
 "where A.StockCode in ('SB-12-073','SB-18-088')" did I do that right?

Comment: What app are you using for the sql-query? It's not my forte so I'm not sure how strict the app is with a leading `Select *` statement and spaces between the options in the `IN` clause.

Comment: @JvdV This is the built in EXCEL VBA App but It's being queried off of Microsoft SQL Server. Now I AM getting a SQL Syntax Error, but I'm not sure if that's simply because I made an error with where I put my " 's and my ( 's or if it's got to do with this long string. There are no spaces between the options when using the textjoin, so I shouldn't encounter any issues?

Comment: I have little to no experience if it comes to that so I can't tell you for sure but usually there would be a `SELECT` and `FROM` statement followed by the `WHERE` clause and `IN` which seems fine syntax-wise. Examples shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to concatenate string is using the `TEXTJOIN()` worksheet function, as in this example:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,A1:C1)
```

Here, the comma is used a delimiter and `FALSE` mentions how to deal with empty cells. As you see, you don't need to add a comma at the end, so your problem won't appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrapped around like this to get rid of the last character:

```
=LEFT(A1;LEN(A1)-1)
```

cell A1 can be your formula instead.